# How to pass a variable from a function in jsp to a java class

Tags: java, jsp

I'm having a function `decider()` and an variable inside the fuction `var data` in a JSP page `xyz.jsp`. Now I need that variable in my java class `Hello.java`. How can I pass it ?

`xyz.jsp`:

```
{
    function decider() {
    var data="my name";
}
```

I need the var in my another java class. How can I do it ?

Comment: Store that in a hidden field, then send a request to the servlet passing that field as parameter

Comment: Do you want to send the variable value on form submit?

Comment: Do you know the difference between client- and server-side technologies?

Answer (score 0):

If your JSP has a form you can populate hidden field inside form and send it to server. The server can access the hidden field `request.getParameter("hiddenField").`

Answer (score 0):

At your xyz.jsp insert param to it and bring them to java file. For example :

First you can bring the `data var` data to mainform as hidden field.

### xyz.jsp

```
function decider() 
{
    var data="my name";
    document.mainform.NAME.value = data;
}
<input type="hidden" name="NAME">
```

### Submit the form action link to another page called test.jsp

```
<jsp:useBean id="hello" scope="page" class="com.home.home.record" /> // hello.java

String FIRSTNAME = request.getParameter("NAME");
int iRowAffected = 0;

// bring param FIRSTNAME to record.java file with function insert data

iRowAffected = hello.insert_data(FIRSTNAME); 
if(iRowAffected == 0) 
{
       throw new NullPointerException("insert_data");
}
```

### hello.java

```
public int insert_data(String FIRSTNAME) throws Exception  
{

  // the rest of coding put inside; 
}
```